# Modify g(n) and f(n) in A* Search

Tags: search-algorithms, artificial-intelligence

I know that the formula for the evaluation function in A* Search is given by:

$f(n)=g(n)+h(n)$

I was wondering what would happen if I made h(n) negative. I suppose it doesn't make sense to have path costs that are positive but an estimate that is negative so maybe I shouldn't be asking this question?

However, let's take the situation where g(n) is negative. This will definitely wreck optimality but what about completeness? And in such a situation, I will probably need to use a negative h(n) anyways because the path costs themselves will be negative. So if I do this, will the resulting search algorithm be complete? (I know it definitely won't be optimal).